# A lot of smoke when using induction stove with any recipe with oil

Tags: temperature, induction, burnt

I recently switched from gas stove to induction. I tried some recipes I could do well with the old stove. Most of them have oil at high heat. However, when switching to induction stove, any time I tried with oil, there always be a lot of smoke coming from the meat. The bottom is usually burnt while the top is not cooked yet.

I usually set the temperature to 150-200oC and put oil in immediately. Any advice what I should do? Currently I can only cook soup recipes with the induction stove.

EDIT: Sorry I forgot about the oil. I usually use olive oil, but once I tried vegetable and sesame oil too. Still a lot of smoke.

Comment: Have you actually checked the temperature your pan is achieving? You'd need an infrared thermometer, I think... but the general rule is, if your oil is burning, the temperature is too hot. Turn the heat down.

Comment: Induction is really efficient when used with good flat bottom pans

Comment: @Max It happens that my pan has small metal circles in its bottom, the seller told me that would be better for induction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What kind of oil you're using would be helpful but, really, the answer is, whatever temperature it is you set it at, it's too hot.

Turn the temperature down.

The temperature gauges shouldn't necessarily be trusted to give you a perfect temperature reading. You can use an infrared thermometer to test it but your result tells everything, really.

If your gas stove was underpowered "high" heat may not have really been that high and the induction stove is probably stronger, so you're overheating your pan.

Since you added your oil usage:

Olive oil is a very low smoke point oil (325-375°F/165-190°C), so it should never be heated so much. Some sesame oils are also pretty low (350-410°F/175-210°C), depending.

Vegetable oil (400-450°F/205-230°C) is much better. Soybean or peanut are even higher (450°F/230°C).

Comment: Thanks, I added the oil in the question. Also, the olive oil I use quickly "evaporate" when I use induction stove. I will try again today with 100-130oC, and see the result. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

> I usually set the temperature to 150-200oC

Forget the temperature setting of your induction stove. If it has any sensor at all (some don't), it is a sensor below the plate, far away from your pan and food. It has nothing to do with the real tempearature in your pan, and is a useless gimmick.

Use the normal strength setting, and start with the lowest. If the oil still smokes too much on the lowest setting, put the pan higher (e.g. insert a ceramic tile between the pan and plate), or use a different pan (steel will heat less than cast iron, for example) or cook larger amounts of food.

Comment: I have used an induction stove and it's really a matter of lowering the setting. Higher settings are great for bringing stocks to a boil quickly.

Comment: Also, with the stove, they should provide a guide. The lowest setting should be great for melting chocolate, or something

Comment: @BaffledCook I have had 2 induction stoves, and both of them were too strong for melting chocolate even on the lowest setting, at least in amounts typical for making a single cake. It's a nice idea, but did not work for me.

Comment: I can't remember how I used to melt chocolate. I've been using a [brand name kitchen robot] for that ever since I bought it.

Comment: Some induction stoves are so slow regulating even if not used at full power ... that your best bet is to just leave the thing on full blast and control heat with distance, use of movement and choice of cookware :)